# A backreference to a branch reset group

Tags: php, regex, pcre, php-7, php-5.6

**Disclaimer**: I do not need another *better* regular expression without reset groups. I need to understand why the output is different for `PHP 5` and `PHP 7`.

**Problem**: I tried to use a branch reset group to match a string using `PHP` which consists of groups of digits separated by different separators.

```
$string = '12-34-56-78';
$pattern = '/^\d{2}(?|(---)|(-)|(\.)|(\:))\d{2}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/';
$matches = preg_match($pattern, $string) === 1;
var_dump($matches);
```

Unfortunately [it works only](https://3v4l.org/ndQQ8) for `PHP < 7`. I also checked the version of the `libpcre` and it's not the source of the problem. The same version of the `libpcre` returns different results for different `PHP` versions.

I wasn't able to find any references to what and why changed in `PHP 7`.

**Question**: why the output different for `PHP 5` and `PHP 7`? Is it an expected behavior for `PHP 7`?

**Update**: seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74612).

Comment: You do not need any branch reset here because you need to refer to the whole group value. A mere [`^\d{2}(---|[-.:])\d{2}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/oqj4Ux/1) will work in every version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you again. I know I can use another `regex`. But this is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: I think we can reduce this to `$string = '--';
$pattern = '/^(?|(---)|(-)\1)/';` and observe the same behaviour.

Comment: The whole duplicate group functionality is not working in PHP 7, the `'/(?J)^\d{2}(?|(?<f>---)|(?<f>-)|(?<f>\.)|(?<f>:))\d{2}\g{f}\d{2}\g{f}\d{2}$/'` does not work either.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend more on the bound `libpcre`/`PCRE_VERSION` than the PHP runtime? -- Also could you make the regex `/x` more spacey here - for decorative purposes?

Comment: @mario I'm sorry I don't get it how to make it more spacey. I think the pattern should be as simple as possible.

Comment: @mario I also checked the version of the `libpcre` and no, it's not the source of the problem. https://3v4l.org/ndQQ8

Comment: Interesting but without modifying branch reset constructor, this works [`^\d+(?|(---)|(-)|(\.)|(\:))\d+\1\d+\1\d+$`](https://3v4l.org/OmkaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74612) and it was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `preg_match` returns 0 and not FALSE ?

**Edit**

Still don't know why but inverting `(-)` and `(---)` solve the problem :

`/^\d{2}(?|(-)|(---)|(\.)|(\:))\d{2}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vAdON)

**Edit 2**

With PHP 7, it seems only the first subpattern works. The regex will also be falsy with the following code :

```
$string = '12.34.56.78'; 
$string = '12:34:56:78'; 
$string = '12---34---56---78';
```

Maybe a PCRE bug because branch reset synatx seems correct to me.

Comment: But it's not POSIX, it's PCRE.

Comment: My mistake. Changed.

Comment: Good question. I've checked it and yes, it returns `0`. Updated the link to the snippet as well.

Comment: inverting `(-)` and `(---)` solve the problem but I still don't know why... ^^

Comment: Nice catch. This may probably be a bug.

Comment: Edit 2 : It really seems to be a bug with branch reset and PCRE

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a bug for me too. Reported. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74612